# Facebook comments in Tab with moderation tools

Tags: facebook, comments, fbml

All of this is done in a Facebook Tab.

I wanted initially to used the social plugin explained here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ 
and did not work at all ( the stream was not displayed there )

After that i used

```
<fb:comments xid="158805454198147" numposts="3" canpost="true" candelete="false" url="https://fblinkvwbeetle.netomat.de/application/">


</fb:comments>
```

I did not manage to add administrators to this comment stream. Because this is done in a Facebook tab ( I believe ) the meta tag did not work.

```
<meta property="fb:moderator" content="FACEBOOK-PROFILE-ID"/>
```

And seems to be ignored.

How can I set up moderators for my comment stream in a Facebook Tab ?